# Webmatrix Site Publish on Azure VM through Web Deploy

Tags: webmatrix, microsoft-web-deploy

I am unable to publish my web application through Webmatrix 2. Can anyone throw some light?

I followed these steps:

a) Created a VM through Azure portal

b) Created endpoints for Web deploy on port 8172 and tcp port 80

c) RDPed to Win Server-08-R2-Sp1-Jun-12 and installed Web Platform 4.0

d) Installed IIS 7 Recommended Configuration

e) Installed Webmatrix 2 on Server which in turn installed Dot Net 4.0, Web Deploy

f) Installed IIS Role Services - Management Services and changed property to [Auto Start] and restarted

g) Edited [Permissions] for the Default Website Folder and added [Network Service] and set [Read/Write/Manage] permissions.

h) Verified that Web deploy and Web Management Service are running in Services.

i) Checked the website from browser and can see the IIS start up page

j) Ran ServerValidator UI application on the Server and it confirms that web management service etc. are running fine

k) After these steps when I put in all parameters in Webmatrix Publish Settings (my ac/ is Admin on Server) I get "Unable to establish connection" error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Web Deploy "handler" (or WMSvc) component was not installed becuase when you installed Web Deploy you had not yet enabled WMSvc (Management Service). The installer only tries the handler component when WMSvc is already installed. You should be able to remedy this by Changing the Web Deploy installation (from Add Remove Programs) and selecting the "IIS 7 Deployment Handler" (with child components Configure for Non-Administrator publishing and Management Service Delegation UI).

One way to avoid this in future would be to install instead the "Recommended Configuration for Hosting Servers" product in WebPI (a very large bundle of server-side items) or at least use the "Web Deploy for Hosting Servers" product (which will automatically make sure to install IIS with Management Service first). If you don't see "Web Deploy for Hosting Servers" by default, try searching for products with "Web Deploy" using the search box.